# plot filled area with line on top

Tags: matlab, plot

I do not manage to change the order of plotted elements in this figure.

I would like to plot the **line** plot **over** the filled **area[image: area]**.

The line should **always** be visible.

```
figure
yyaxis left
h = plot([0 10],[0 10],'LineWidth',5);
yyaxis right
f = fill([3 3 6 6],[0 10 10 0],'r');

% this does not work
h.ZData = ones(size(h.XData));
f.ZData = zeros(size(f.XData));

% using area instead of fill does not help

% plotting yyaxis right before yyaxis left does not help
```

I found a **work-around solution** by **changing what is plotted in yyaxis left and yyaxis right**.

The line is now plotted on top of the area.

However, the position of the axes is also switched. 
I would like to keep it the way it is now (line should belong to left axis, area should belong to the right axis) since it looks nicer when I label it this way:

```
figure
yyaxis right
h = plot([0 10],[0 10],'LineWidth',5,'color','b');
yyaxis left
f = fill([3 3 6 6],[0 1 1 0],'r');
```

**I managed to get it working** with a combination of the **hint from @LuisMendo** and changing the 'ZData' attribute of my filled areas. Thank you all for your help!

Comment: changing the order of yyaxis left and right does not help

Comment: I need to plot it in two different axes (left and right)

Comment: Not sure why (there are two axes involved, not one), but `set(gca, 'sortmethod', 'depth')` works

Comment: @LuisMendo thanks for the hint. I upvoted it. I'm not totally satisfied with this solution since in reality I have multiple filled areas in one yyaxis and your solution messes with the order of these areas. However, I will further investigate the issue based on your solution.

Comment: Try `uistack(h, 'top')`; where `h` is the handle of the line. This places the line on top of everything else in those axes.

Comment: @user7431005 My main doubt now is: do `yyleft right` and `yyaxis left` create two different axes? It would seem so, but running `hl = gca;` after `plot` and `hr = gca;` after `fill` gives the second axis _in both cases_, as can be checked with `get(hl, 'children'), get(hr, 'children')`

Comment: @LuisMendo: I think there is just one axes object, and `yyaxis right` and `yyaxis left` "activate" different sides of it.

Comment: The easiest solution will be to plot the line on `yyaxis right` and not left since it look like matlab always put the `yyaxis right` object on the top. But the two axis will be switched.

Comment: @obchardon This is identical to my work-around solution posted in the question.

Comment: @gnovice What confuses me is that neither `get(get(h, 'parent'), 'children')` nor `get(get(f, 'parent'), 'children')` give the `plot` object as their child

Comment: @gnovice I've doing some tests. It seems like there is _only one_ axis, like you said (and the `'parent'` property of all objects refers to that axis, as expected); but the `'children'` property of the axis only lists _one object_, namely the one that was plotted, or clicked on, last. Weird

Comment: I've posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59760632/2586922) about this behaviour of `yyaxis`