# Behaviour of axis properties with 'yyaxis'

Tags: matlab, graphics, matlab-figure

Create a figure with two y-axes, using [`yyaxis`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/yyaxis.html):

```
figure
yyaxis left
hl = plot([0 10],[0 10],'-');
yyaxis right
hr = plot([0 10],[10 0],'--');
```

The following curious behaviour has been found. This has been tested in R2017b and in R2019a on Windows 10.

The objects `hl` and `hr` seem to belong to the **same axis** (that is, `yyaxis` does not create a new axis):

```
>> get(hr, 'parent')==get(hl, 'parent')
ans =
  logical
   1
```

However, the `'children'` property of the axis **only reflects one object**:

```
>> get(get(get(hl, 'parent'), 'children'), 'LineStyle')
ans =
    '--'
>> get(get(get(hr, 'parent'), 'children'), 'LineStyle')
ans =
    '--'
```

Also, the `YAxisLocation'` property of the parent axis has **the same value** for both objects:

```
>> get(get(hl, 'parent'), 'YAxisLocation')
ans =
    'right'
>> get(get(hr, 'parent'), 'YAxisLocation')
ans =
    'right'
```

If we now click on the solid line, to make it the current object,

```
>> get(get(get(gco, 'parent'), 'children'), 'LineStyle')
ans =
    '-'
>> get(get(get(hl, 'parent'), 'children'), 'LineStyle')
ans =
    '-'
>> get(get(get(hr, 'parent'), 'children'), 'LineStyle')
ans =
    '-'
>> get(get(gco, 'parent'), 'YAxisLocation')
ans =
    'left'
```

Similarly, if we now click on the dotted line,

```
>> get(get(get(gco, 'parent'), 'children'), 'LineStyle')
ans =
    '--'
>> get(get(get(hl, 'parent'), 'children'), 'LineStyle')
ans =
    '--'
>> get(get(get(hr, 'parent'), 'children'), 'LineStyle')
ans =
    '--'
>> get(get(gco, 'parent'), 'YAxisLocation')
ans =
    'right'
```

As a check,

```
>> get(gcf, 'children')
```

gives only one axis too, and

```
>> get(get(gcf, 'children'), 'children')
```

behaves similarly: only the object that was plotted last, or thas has been made current, is listed.

The above behaviour can be **summarized** as follows:

- There is **only one** axis (and the `'parent'` property of all objects refers to that axis, as expected).
- The `'children'` property of the axis lists **only one object**, namely the current object, or the object that was plotted last.
- The `'YAxisLocation'` property of the axis **dynamically changes** between `'left'` and `'right'`. Again, this is determined by the current object, or the object that was plotted last.

It's not clear how to make sense of this behaviour. The following **questions** naturally arise:

- Is this documented somewhere?
- How can two objects have the same axis as `'parent'`, but that axis only has the current object as `'children'`?
- Why does the `'YAxisLocation'` also change depending on which the current object is?

Comment: From [the docs](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/yyaxis.html): "`yyaxis left` activates the side of the current axes associated with the left y-axis. Subsequent graphics commands target the left side." And "The `Children` property of the `Axes` object only contains the children for the active side. To access all the children for both sides, use the `allchild` function.". So this is sort of documented, though awkward behavior. `yyaxis` is, unhelpfully, a P-file.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Aah, so the current object determines the active side, and handles to the side are hidden. The active side also changes the `'YAxisLocation'` property. I should have read the documentation :-) Care to post an answer?

Comment: I'm still looking into this. `get(gca,'YAxis')` returns an array with two values: one ruler for each side. But the `YAxisLocation`, `YLim`, `YTick`, etc. describe only the active side.

Comment: The more I look into this, the more confused I am. I'm not sure that what I typed below is a true answer, but maybe it adds a bit of information.

Comment: Something else weird: `allchild(h)` calls `getAllchildChildren(h)` (it's an M-file). `getAllchildChildren` is a method of `matlab.graphics.axis.Axes`. `help matlab.graphics.axis.Axes.getAllchildChildren` says: "The contents of the comment field should go here." ... That's useful!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To me it looks like `yyaxis` does some nasty-behind-the-scenes things and there's lots of hidden data we can't access.

The [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/yyaxis.html) does say that:

> `yyaxis left` activates the side of the current axes associated with the left y-axis. Subsequent graphics commands target the left side.

and

> The `Children` property of the `Axes` object only contains the children for the active side. To access all the children for both sides, use the `allchild` function.

Changing the "side" with `yyaxis` therefore changes the contents of the `Axes` object, I presume that the contents for the other side gets stored in some hidden location that I haven't been able to find. `yyaxis` is P-code, so we won't be able to figure out what exactly it is doing.

This is interesting:

```matlab
figure
yyaxis left
hl = plot([0 10],[0 1],'-');
yyaxis right
hr = plot([0 10],[100 0],'--');

h = gca;

yyaxis left
h.YLim

yyaxis right
h.YLim
```

The code creates left and right axes with different limits. We get the handle to the axes, change to left, read the limits from the handle, then change to right and read the same property again. The first time it returns `[0,1]`, the second time it is `[0,100]`. That is, the `Axes` object with handle `h` changes when we call `yyaxis`.

The only indication I've found that `h` points to axes with two sides is that `h.YAxis` returns two handles to `NumericRuler` objects, one for each side.

---

I can't but feel this is awkward behavior. I would have expected there to be two `Axes` objects, both with the same `Position` property, and maybe with listeners that keep the two in sync.