# Why is my axis position data changing when I use copyobj in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, graphics, figure, axes

I'm creating a plot in Matlab with two axes, and I want to copy the entire figure to a smaller window with a specific size, and then save it (this makes it easier to format plots for display in Word documents). The function I'm using is as follows:

```matlab
function printStandardFigure(figInput,filename)
     dpi = 300;

     newFig = copyobj(figInput,groot);

     newFig.Units = 'inches';
     newFig.InnerPosition = [1,1,6.5/2,6.5/2];

     print(filename,'-dpng',['-r',num2str(dpi)]);

     close(newFig);
end
```

In theory, this should create a copy of the figure I've made with all its axes, etc. identical to the original but resized to fit the new window size. What actually happens is that the `'Position'` property for one of the axes gets reset to [0, 0, 1, 1], but the other one displays just fine. This still happens even when I set the `ActivePositionProperty` to `'position'`, which normally causes the axis to hold the `Position` property constant.

I've also tried using `copyobj` to copy just the two axes over to the new figure, but I have similar issues with resizing, and this doesn't import any legends even though they are set as children of the axes.

This code works just fine if I only have one axis, so why does the second axis cause it to screw up? I've tried making the original figure have the same aspect ratio as the new one, and I've tried setting their sizes to be exactly equal using the `InnerPosition` property. I can't figure out what's going on and Matlab's documentation isn't helping.

[Here's the original chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phZSi.png)

[And here's what the output of my function looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6mee.png)

Edit: Cris Luengo in the comments suggested I try the `subplot` command, which I thought was a good idea, so I tried it out. However, the export process is still causing a problem Here are the [original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vz9Fu.png) and the [exported](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GniAl.png) versions of the plot when I do that. The original figure was created to have the same dimensions as the exported plot, just to make sure that resizing the axes wasn't causing the issue. I also get the same problem when I remove lines 6 and 7 from the export function (where I set the size of the new figure).

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you show some print screen image with the issue?

Comment: Instead of copying the figure, use the figure's PaperPosition and PaperUnits properties to determine the size at with they are exported. Also, I would guess you bumped into a bug in MATLAB. Are you running the latest version? If so, consider submitting a bug report.

Comment: PaperPosition has the same issue. I'm using r2019a. Alexey, I've uploaded pictures of the original and the output charts.

Comment: Oh, you are using `yyaxis`! That’s an odd one. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59760632/7328782 — I’m not surprised this is bugged. You should definitely submit a bug report. As a workaround, don’t use `yyaxis`, two y-axes in the same plot is  only useful to confuse your readers. Just use two separate axes with `subplot`.

Comment: Oh, I guess it’s two x-axes you use, but the same holds. Needless confusion. Better two horizontally arranged plots with a shared y-axis.

Comment: I'm using two separate axes plotted together using the `axes` graphics object, not `yyaxes`. I did read that there were some problems with `copyobj` and `yyaxes` but I thought my way would work. I'd rather keep the two curves overlapping for comparison instead of separating them with `subplot`, but I guess if that just isn't possible...

Comment: Cris, I tried the subplot idea and I'm having a similar issue. The axes display fine in the original figure, but when I export the figure they change size, which causes text to overlap and makes the plot generally unreadable.

Comment: I've never seen anything like this. What version of MATLAB are you using? On what OS? -- BTW: use `@cris` in your comment to ping me. I only saw your comment by chance, because you updated the question.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I'm using MATLAB r2019a on Windows 10, latest version (thanks for telling me about the ping, btw).

Comment: @AlexeyNovakov I've added pictures to the original question.